# Powershell V3 new ScheduleJob and ScheduleTask cmdlets

Tags: powershell, task, jobs, schedule

I'm currently learning all about the new cmd-lets in powershell version 3 and attempting to use some of them.

I'm in need to schedule different things and I'm trying to learn the new new-scheduledtask and new-scheduledjob cmdlets but I'm having a little difficulty.

I was wondering if anyone can help me discover what would be the simplest way to schedule a service restart (apache in this case), via a script?  the script would schedule a restart when a certain condition is met ( basically when I need to restart to add new apache vhosts).

Any ideas?  Currently I'm leaning towards creating a scriptblock that will do it and then registering a job and then a job trigger for the time of the day I want to restart which would be that night that the script schedules the restart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<#So Here's an exmaple i thought to bring up for you it does a daily restart of BITS Service at 3am,i guess you can modify the script with your apache service example#>

<#Here Im Creating a Trigger for the Job and im setting it to start at 3am daily#>

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At 3am
```

<# Below Im Registering the ScheduledJob with a Name of  and a trigger of $trigger which is at daily 3am,  Also im placing the script to be executed inside of a script block#>

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name BitsServiceRestart -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock {

<# Suppose Lets say that you want to schedule a restart of BITS Service#>
Restart-Service -ServiceName BITS

}
```

<# Once the Job is registered you can get the Job details using Get-ScheduledJob
 You can also view task details using TaskScheduler --> Windows --> PowerShell #>

```
Get-ScheduledJob BitsServiceRestart | fl *
```

<# You can recieve the output of Scheduled Job using Recieve Job #>

```
Receive-Job -Name BitsServiceRestart
```

Comment: I haven't replied in a long time but that answered my question and I wanted to let you know that.  Thanks!